# How to improve the performance in R for below code

Tags: r, performance, for-loop

I am trying to sum the value to a previous value of the same column based on a condition. My code is as below, But it takes forever to run. How should I optimize it

```
df <- data.frame(a=rnorm(1:150000),
         b=rnorm(1:150000))
df$d<-lag(df$b)
df$c<-0
for(row in 1:dim(df)[1]){df[row,]<-mutate(
  df[1:row,],c=ifelse(df[1:row,2]==df[1:row,3],4,lag(c,1)+1))[row,]}
```

I have tried doing this on a smaller piece of data which had the below code

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,4,3,1),
         b=c(3,3,2,1,4))
df$d<-lag(df$b)
df$c<-0
```

Input:

```
> df
  a b d c
1 1 3 NA 0
2 2 3 3 0
3 4 2 3 0
4 3 1 2 0
5 1 4 1 0


for(row in 1:dim(df)[1]){
 df[row,]<-mutate(df[1:row,], c=ifelse(
      df[1:row,2]==df[1:row,3],4,lag(c,1)+1))[row,]
 }
```

and the output was as expected:

```
a b d c
1 3 NA NA
2 3 3 4
4 2 3 5
3 1 2 6
1 4 1 7
```

But when I run on the 150000 rows it takes forever. Need to optimize it

Comment: Is `mutate` a `dplyr` utility? If not, which packages are you using?

Comment: All this does when I test it (on 1500 samples) is set `df$c` to NA everywhere.

Comment: a b d c
1 3 NA NA
2 3 3 4
4 2 3 5
3 1 2 6
1 4 1 7

Comment: @spacedman Yes I know. That might be because I have put it norm for randomization. but a and b are not norm. I have updated the expected output. It needs to lag column c by itself

Comment: Can you explain what are you doing with small data example? for example, when n is 5. Also it would be better if you editted your post, not write comments

Comment: does this require more memory than physically available ? if your app causes your system to swap, then you should first try to run on an other system with more RAM

Comment: @tejkiran update my answer. I hope it is what you wanted..

Comment: @tejkiran 'Sorry guess updated my input wrongly.. updated the same' What does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you provide example which shows how your function is working? Because running your code returns:

```
> df
  a b d c
1 1 3 3 4
2 2 3 3 4
3 4 2 2 4
4 3 1 1 4
5 1 4 4 4
```

Do you want that column `c` is constant?

If not, then currently i can only guess that you want something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,4,3,1),
                 b=c(3,3,2,1,4),
                 d=c(3,1,2,0,4))
require(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df)
dt[, c := ifelse(b == d, T, F)]
dt[, c := cumsum(c)]
dt
   a b d c
1: 1 3 3 1
2: 2 3 1 1
3: 4 2 2 2
4: 3 1 0 2
5: 1 4 4 3
```

(if b ==d then c increases by 1)
Or you want something else?

### Update:

So i think I got what you want:

```
require(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,4,3,1),
                 b=c(3,3,2,1,4))
df$d<-lag(df$b)
df$c<-0
df

yourFunction <- function(df) {
  require(dplyr)
  for(row in 1:dim(df)[1]){
    cd <- df[1:row,]
    df[row,] <- mutate(cd,
                       c = ifelse(cd[,2] == cd[,3], 4, lag(c, 1) + 1))[row,]
  }
  return(df)
}
r1 <- yourFunction(df)
```

fast `data.table` function (could use also only base functions):

```
myfunction1 <- function(df) {
  require(data.table)
  dt <- as.data.table(df)
  dt[, cc := ifelse(b != d, F, T)]
  cumsum2 <- function(x) {
    x[is.na(x)] <- 0
    cumsum(x)
  }
  dt[, cc := cumsum2(cc)]
  # dt[, c := ifelse(b != d, 1, 4)]
  dt[, c := ifelse(b != d, 1L, 4L)]
  # dt[, c := cumsum2(c), by = cc]
  dt[, c := as.integer(cumsum2(c)), by = cc]

  dt[, cc := NULL]
  dt[c == 0, c := NA]
  dt[]
}

r2 <- myfunction1(df)
```

test if c column are equal:

```
all.equal(r1$c, r2$c)
[1] TRUE
```

Now we can test speed on larger data set:

```
## larger test
n <- 1000
set.seed(10)
df <- data.frame(a = rbinom(n, 10, 0.2),
                 b = rbinom(n, 10, 0.2))
df$d<-lag(df$b)
df$c<-0

require(rbenchmark)
benchmark(r1 <- yourFunction(df),
          r2 <- myfunction1(df), replications = 5)
                        test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
1 r1 <- yourFunction(df)            5   19.92      664     15.18     1.84         NA        NA
2  r2 <- myfunction1(df)            5    0.03        1      0.01     0.00         NA        NA
all.equal(r1$c, r2$c)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Sorry guess updated my input wrongly.. updated the same

Comment: @tejkiran I got something wrong? can you try to explain what? But if it is correct and helped you, you should accept it..